# Hide jQuery modal box content

Tags: jquery, html, popup, modal-dialog

We have the following code that pops up on load of our website once every three days with a cookie. It uses the Reveal modal popup.

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
<p>Text here</p>
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

The code only shows when the page loads, as it should, except in Chrome for the iPad. Instead of a popup, the content is shown on the page as if it were a standard object. I've put it at the foot of the page to be as out of the way as possible. I tried wrapping the above code like this:

```
<div style="display: none">
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
<p>Text here</p>
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
</div>
```

...but that not only hides the content it also renders the popup nonfunctional, i.e. the content is hidden so the popup seems to have nothing to display.

It functions correctly even on the iPhone version of Chrome, just not the iPad version. Maybe I shouldn't sweat it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you set `display: none` on `myModal` and then control that `display` property in your pop-up code?

Comment: do you want to post some more of your code and I'll have a fiddle?  Ii'm just trying to throw in an idea to get it working on the Chrome iPad config...  I can't test that here!  (maybe you shouldn't worry too much ;-)

Comment: Yeah this might be something I should notify Reveal about as a bug. It works perfectly in every other browser (desktop: Safari, Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox... and iPhone: Safari, Chrome... and iPad: Safari. Just not Chrome. Odd!